# Program printing garbage value into file

Tags: c++, file-io

This is my class :

```
class User{
    char name[40], address[50], phone[15];
    long uid; int password;
    char acctType;
    float acctBalance;
    void GenerateIdPassword();
    int GetPassword();
public :
    int NewAccount();
    int LoginToAccount();
    void DisplayAccountDetails();
    int GetAcctNumber();
    float GetBalance();
    void Deposit(float);
    void Withdraw(float);
    void ChangePassword();
    void StoreData(User);
};
```

Note : I haven't included any member function definitions.

```
void User::StoreData(User u)
{
    fstream fio;
    long p;
    User t;
    fio.open("UserAccounts.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    while(fio) {
        p = fio.tellg();
        fio.read((char*)&t, sizeof(t));
        if(u.uid == t.uid) {
            fio.seekp(p);
            fio.write((char*) &u, sizeof(u));
            break;
        }
    }
    fio.close();
}
```

This function modifies a record in the file if the user has actually modified any information related to his account.

If I modify an account from this file in the end I get garbage value in the file.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Open the file in binary mode, not text mode.

Comment: Why are you storing non-text in a ”.txt” file?

Comment: So then if I store non-string variables I should use the file in binary mode. Okay but the file was working all right until this update operation. I could just store and retrieve data. So what did I miss?

Comment: *but the file was working all right* -- Now it doesn't work "all right".  What's the point of bringing up how it was working before you made the change in the code? Obviously the text mode now is showing you the flaws, while before it didn't.

Comment: Because I like to find the exact reason of a issue. I will try out binary mode. Thanks

Comment: The simple explanation is that text mode will interpret certain control characters to mean specific things, such as end-of-file, carriage-return, etc.  For example, you write a 0x26 to a Windows text file, you aren't going to get back 0x26, but an EOF when reading the file back in text mode.  Binary mode writes the bytes as-is -- no translation, no interpretation, etc.  So for your case, you were just lucky you didn't run into these issues.

Comment: Also, note that this code, even in binary mode, will not work for classes or structs that are not POD (Plain-Old-Data).  For example, if one of those members was a `std::vector` or `std::string`, this method of writing files and reading them back will not work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It is working fine now. And yes I did try to use string and as you said it didn't work. I learned c++ 2 years back and I thought the best way to revise would be to just browse through the books by Schildt and making a small project. I will see into strings and vectors. Thanks again!